# Difference between constrained optimization and unconstrained optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, math, computer-science

What is the property that makes an optimization problem unconstrained?

Comment: Voting to close, well off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

This is a broad question. Some examples:

Constraint optimization: make the largest water tank using no more than 1 kg of steel.
Unconstrained optimization: make the largest water tank :)
Constrained: fastest route to a mall through a strip club.
Unconstrained: fastest route to a mall.

Constrained optimization is the most practical and hence useful type. It is also a bit harder.

Sorry if this is not what you are looking for. Did you want a mathematical explanation rather?

Comment: Yes a little more rigorous answer would be fine.

Comment: Well in that case http://tinyurl.com/283q244

Comment: You ask me if I want a mathematical answer and when I say yes, you give me that link.

Comment: +1 Good constrained answer to an unconstrained question.

Comment: Well, I googled the term and realized that everything one would need to get a good answer is listed in the first 5 links. I figured I would share my research skills with others.